# How to read the content of sub tag along with the parent tag of XML in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am new to Java and am trying to write a program that gets the meaning of a given word from MW api. The output is XML, now I am using DOM parser to print the list of all definitions. Normally the retrieved XML will be as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<entry_list version="1.0">
    <entry id="dictionary"><ew>dictionary</ew><subj>PU-1#PU-2#PU-3#CP-4</subj><hw>dic*tio*nary</hw><sound><wav>dictio04.wav</wav></sound><pr>Ëˆdik-shÉ™-ËŒner-Ä“, -ËŒne-rÄ“</pr><fl>noun</fl><in><il>plural</il> <if>dic*tio*nar*ies</if></in><et>Medieval Latin <it>dictionarium,</it> from Late Latin <it>diction-, dictio</it> word, from Latin, speaking</et><def><date>1526</date> <sn>1</sn> <dt>:a reference source in print or electronic form containing words usually alphabetically arranged along with information about their forms, <d_link>pronunciations</d_link>, functions, <d_link>etymologies</d_link>, meanings, and <d_link>syntactical</d_link> and idiomatic uses</dt> <sn>2</sn> <dt>:a reference book listing alphabetically terms or names important to a particular subject or activity along with discussion of their meanings and <d_link>applications</d_link></dt> <sn>3</sn> <dt>:a reference book listing alphabetically the words of one language and showing their meanings or translations in another language</dt> <sn>4</sn> <dt>:a <d_link>computerized</d_link> list (as of items of data or words) used for reference (as for information retrieval or word processing)</dt></def></entry>
</entry_list>
```

The list of definitions will be enclosed inside the tag `<dt>`

Now the problem I am facing is inside the tag `<dt>` there is another sub tag `<d_link>`. Whenever the DOM parser runs across this sub tag, the `getNodeValue()` method is considering the end of the tag `<dt>`

My Code is as below:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;

public class Dictionary5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String head = new String("http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/");
        String word = new String("banal");
        String apiKey = new String("?key=xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"); //My API Key for Merriam webster
        String finalURL = head.trim() + word.trim()+ apiKey.trim();
        try
        {
            DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = b.parse(finalURL);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
            for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node n = items.item(i);

                if (n.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    continue;

                Element e = (Element) n;
                NodeList titleList = e.getElementsByTagName("dt");
                for (int j = 0; j < titleList.getLength(); j++){
                    Node dt = titleList.item(j);
                    if (dt.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                        continue;                   
                    Element titleElem = (Element) titleList.item(j);
                    Node titleNode = titleElem.getChildNodes().item(0);
                    System.out.println(titleNode.getNodeValue());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The output is as following

```
:a reference source in print or electronic form containing words usually alphabetically arranged along with information about their forms, 
:a reference book listing alphabetically terms or names important to a particular subject or activity along with discussion of their meanings and 
:a reference book listing alphabetically the words of one language and showing their meanings or translations in another language
:a
```

As you can see the first, second and fourth definitions are abruptly ended because the parser encounter the sub tag `<d_link>`.

My Expected output is as following:

```
:a reference source in print or electronic form containing words usually alphabetically arranged along with information about their forms, pronunciations, functions, etymologies, meanings, and syntactical and idiomatic uses
:a reference book listing alphabetically terms or names important to a particular subject or activity along with discussion of their meanings and applications
:a reference book listing alphabetically the words of one language and showing their meanings or translations in another language
:a computerized list (as of items of data or words) used for reference (as for information retrieval or word processing)
```

Can someone please help me with this. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the dom model, the content of the the dt tag will be TEXT, d_link element, TEXT, d_link ....

So you want to concatenated all text elements (and it seems that also the content of the d_link tag). You are only reading the first one: titleElem.getChildNodes().item(0) so it is "abruptly" finished

Comment: Thanks for the reply, any suggestions on how to get the number of items and loop it to concat all the text into a single string.